# Elasticsearch ignore words breakers

Tags: elasticsearch

i'm new to Elasticsearch and i've got a problem regarding querying.

I indexed strings like that:

```
my-super-string
my-other-string
my-little-string
```

This strings are slugs. 
So, they are no spaces, only alphanumeric characters. Mapping for the related field is only "type=string".

I'm using a query like this:

```
{ "query":{ "query_string":{ "query": "*"+<MY_QUERY>+"*", "rewrite": "top_terms_10" } }}
```

Where "MY_QUERY" is also a slug. Something like "my-super" for example.

When searching for "my" i get results.

When searching for "my-super" i get no results and i'd like to have "my-super-string".

Can someone help me on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using match_phrase instead of using query string with leading and trailing wildcards. Even standard analyzer should be able to split slug into tokens correctly, so there is not need for wildcards.

```
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/slugs/doc/1" -d '{"slug": "my-super-string"}'
echo
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/slugs/doc/2" -d '{"slug": "my-other-string"}'
echo
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/slugs/doc/3" -d '{"slug": "my-little-string"}'
echo
curl -XPOST "localhost:9200/slugs/_refresh"
echo
echo "Searching for my"
curl "localhost:9200/slugs/doc/_search?pretty=true&fields=slug" -d '{"query" : { "match_phrase": {"slug": "my"} } }'
echo
echo "Searching for my-super"
curl "localhost:9200/slugs/doc/_search?pretty=true&fields=slug" -d '{"query" : { "match_phrase": {"slug": "my-super"} } }'
echo
echo "Searching for my-other"
curl "localhost:9200/slugs/doc/_search?pretty=true&fields=slug" -d '{"query" : { "match_phrase": {"slug": "my-other"} } }'
echo
echo "Searching for string"
curl "localhost:9200/slugs/doc/_search?pretty=true&fields=slug" -d '{"query" : { "match_phrase": {"slug": "string"} } }'
```

Alternatively, you can create your own analyzer that will split slugs into tokens only on "-"

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/slugs
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/slugs -d '{
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "number_of_shards": 1,
            "number_of_replicas": 0,
            "analysis": {
                "analyzer" : {
                    "slug_analyzer" : {
                        "tokenizer": "slug_tokenizer",
                        "filter" : ["lowercase"]
                    }
                },
                "tokenizer" :{
                    "slug_tokenizer" : {
                        "type": "pattern",
                        "pattern": "-"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings" :{
        "doc" : {
            "properties" : {
                "slug" : {"type": "string", "analyzer" : "slug_analyzer"}
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Comment: With the match_phrase i must have an exact match to have results.
 
So i tried the match_phrase_prefix, works well, but i also need a "match_phrase_suffix" if i search "super-s" i'd like to get "my-super-string".

In fact, i'd like to have a simple wildcard like `*-str*` that will match any slug containing "-str"

It's the "-" character i have problem with. Anytime i had one to my query i get no result.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then it's this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467067/how-to-search-for-a-part-of-a-word-with-elasticsearch/6471449#6471449

Comment: Thx you again...
I'm near the final result, but i have still problems with the "-" character.
I really want the exact matchs. I need something like a real exact wildcard (but you said in the other post to not use it ^^).
I don't know how to index, and how to search. If i type "my-super" i want ALL docs containing "my-super". The "-" seems to break everything.