# Elasticsearch how to use multi_match with wildcard

Tags: elasticsearch, wildcard

I have a User object with properties Name and Surname. I want to search these fields using one query, and I found `multi_match` in the documentation, but I don't know how to properly use that with a wildcard. Is it possible?

I tried with a `multi_match` query but it didn't work:

```
{
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "*mar*",
            "fields": [
                "user.name",
                "user.surname"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Alternatively you could use a `query_string` query with wildcards.

```
"query": {
    "query_string": {
        "query": "*mar*",
        "fields": ["user.name", "user.surname"]
    }
}
```

This will be slower than using an nGram filter at index-time (see my other answer), but if you are looking for a quick and dirty solution...

Also I am not sure about your mapping, but if you are using `user.name` instead of `name` your mapping needs to look like this:

```
"your_type_name_here": {
    "properties": {
        "user": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "surname": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The query_string does more than that, it exposes the lucene query syntax. I would rather look at the wildcard query.

Comment: Can you paste a link to details of what `query_string` does? I'm a little confused about the behaviour...

Comment: Look at the bottom of this page for a comparison between query_string and match query: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/match-query/

Comment: The answer is not answering the question how to use multi_match and wildcard. Does someone has an idea?

Comment: elastics docs about multimatch and regexp are such a headache. this worked great, thanks.

Answer (score 20):

Such a query worked for me:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {"query": {"wildcard": {"user.name": {"value": "*mar*"}}}},
            {"query": {"wildcard": {"user.surname": {"value": "*mar*"}}}}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Similar to what you are doing, except that in my case there could be different masks for different fields.

Comment: Thanks catherine Tsokur.  I am also trying the same way but is there a way i can keep multiple wildcard conditions of same column. example : user.name can be of 5 different wildcard patterns. Please suggest how can i use that condition .

Answer (score 12):

I just did this now:

```
GET _search {
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "theDate": {
                            "gte": "2014-01-01",
                            "lte": "2014-12-31"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match" : {
                        "Country": "USA"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "should": [
                {
                    "wildcard" : { "Id_A" : "0*" }
                },
                {
                    "wildcard" : { "Id_B" : "0*" }
                }
            ],"minimum_number_should_match": 1
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Similar to suggestion above, but this is simple and worked for me:

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must":
        [
            {
                "wildcard" : { "processname.keyword" : "*system*" }
            },
            {
                "wildcard" : { "username" : "*admin*" }
            },
            {
                "wildcard" : { "device_name" : "*10*" }
            }
        ]
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It will fail if one is broken. So each of these properties needs the same part of the string..

Answer (score 7):

I would not use wildcards, it will not scale well. You are asking a lot of the search engine at query time. You can use the nGram filter, to do the processing at index-time not search time.

[See this discussion on the nGram filter.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467067/how-to-search-for-a-part-of-a-word-with-elasticsearch/6471449#6471449)

After indexing the `name` and `surname` correctly (change your mapping, there are examples in the above link) you can use multi-match but without wildcards and get the expected results.

Comment: Downside: the index size is going to grow a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
description: {
  type: 'keyword',
  normalizer: 'useLowercase',
},
product: {
      type: 'object',
      properties: {
        name: {
          type: 'keyword',
          normalizer: 'useLowercase',
        },
      },
    },
activity: {
      type: 'object',
      properties: {
        name: {
          type: 'keyword',
          normalizer: 'useLowercase',
        },
      },
    },
```

query:

```
          query: {
            bool: {
              must: [
                {
                  bool: {
                    should: [
                      {
                        wildcard: {
                          description: {
                            value: `*${value ? value : ''}*`,
                            boost: 1.0,
                            rewrite: 'constant_score',
                          },
                        },
                      },
                      {
                        wildcard: {
                          'product.name': {
                            value: `*${value ? value : ''}*`,
                            boost: 1.0,
                            rewrite: 'constant_score',
                          },
                        },
                      },
                      {
                        wildcard: {
                          'activity.name': {
                            value: `*${value ? value : ''}*`,
                            boost: 1.0,
                            rewrite: 'constant_score',
                          },
                        },
                      },
                    ],
                  },
                },
                {
                  match: {
                    recordStatus: RecordStatus.Active,
                  },
                },
                {
                  bool: {
                    must_not: [
                      {
                        term: {
                          'user.id': req.currentUser?.id,
                        },
                      },
                    ],
                  },
                },
                {
                  bool: {
                    should: tags
                      ? tags.map((name: string) => {
                          return {
                            nested: {
                              path: 'tags',
                              query: {
                                match: {
                                  'tags.name': name,
                                },
                              },
                            },
                          };
                        })
                      : [],
                  },
                },
              ],
              filter: {
                bool: {
                  must_not: {
                    terms: {
                      id: existingIds ? existingIds : [],
                    },
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          },
          sort: [
            {
              updatedAt: {
                order: 'desc',
              },
            },
          ],
```