# Elasticsearch Nest Query not returning result as expected

Tags: c#-4.0, elasticsearch, nest

I'm new to Elasticsearch. I'm trying a query and when giving full name I'm getting results. When I give part of it, it's not returning any results. Below is the sample that I have been trying.

```
   {
     "query": {
     "multi_match": {
     "query": "recharge",
      "fields":     ["category.*","categoryName^3","alterNames","categoryDescription"],
      "type": "best_fields"
    }
  },size:1000
  }
```

If I pass "rech" in the query, I'm not getting any results. Can any one help me here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ElasticSearch how to use multi\_match with wildcard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16933800/elasticsearch-how-to-use-multi-match-with-wildcard)

Comment: How are each of the fields analyzed at index time?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want to get the results with unfinished `query`, so you need a wildcard, like this:

```
{
  "query": {
  "multi_match": {
    "query": "rech*",
    "fields": ["category.*", "categoryName^3", "alterNames", "categoryDescription"],
    "type": "best_fields"
  }
}
```