# Elasticsearch search pattern with Start string

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch and trying to implement search. Below is my index and settings`curl -XPUT localhost:9200/rets_data/ -d '{
   "settings":{
      "index":{
         "analysis":{
            "analyzer":{
               "analyzer_startswith":{
                  "tokenizer":"keyword",
                  "filter":"lowercase"
               },
               "analyzer_whitespacewith":{
                  "tokenizer":"whitespace",
                  "filter":"lowercase"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings":{
      "city":{
         "properties":{
            "CityName":{
               "analyzer":"analyzer_startswith",
               "type":"string"
            }
         }
      },
      "rets_aux_subdivision":{
         "properties":{
            "nn":{
               "analyzer":"analyzer_whitespacewith",
               "type":"string"
            },
            "field_LIST_77":{
               "analyzer":"analyzer_whitespacewith",
               "type":"string"
            },
            "SubDivisionName":{
               "analyzer":"analyzer_whitespacewith",
               "type":"string"
            },
            "SubDivisionAlias":{
               "analyzer":"analyzer_whitespacewith",
               "type":"string"
            }
         }
      },
      "rental_aux_subdivision":{
         "properties":{
            "nn":{
               "analyzer":"analyzer_whitespacewith",
               "type":"string"
            },
            "field_LIST_77":{
               "analyzer":"analyzer_whitespacewith",
               "type":"string"
            },
            "SubDivisionName":{
               "analyzer":"analyzer_whitespacewith",
               "type":"string"
            },
            "SubDivisionAlias":{
               "analyzer":"analyzer_whitespacewith",
               "type":"string"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'`

Below is search string

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/rets_data/rets_aux_subdivision/_search?pretty -d '{"query":{"match_phrase_prefix":{"nn":{"query":"boca w","max_expansions":50}}},"sort":{"total":{"order":"desc"}},"size":100}'
```

When i am searching for any text like "Boca r", "Boca w" it is not giving me result.

My expected result is below.

"Boca w" should give me result starting with "Boca w". i.e "Boca west", "Boca Woods", "Boca Winds"

Please help me on this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post one sample document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use edgeNgram. Check this out in elasticsearch documentation.
 EdgeNgram filter prepare multiple words from one like this:

> Woods->[W,Wo,Woo,Wood,Woods]

It makes index bigger, but searching will be more efficient than any other option like wildcards etc. Here is my simple index creation with ngrams on title.ngram:

```
{
"settings" : {
"index" : {
"analysis" : {
    "analyzer" : {
        "ngram_analyzer" : {
        "type" : "custom",
        "tokenizer" : "standard",
        "filter" : ["lowercase","my_ngram"]
        }
    },
    "filter" : {
    "my_ngram" : {
    "type" : "edge_ngram",
    "min_gram" : 1,
    "max_gram" : 50
    }
}
}
}
},
  "mappings": 
  {
    "post":
    {
    "properties": 
      {

        "id": 
        {
            "type": "integer",
            "index":"no"
         },
        "title": 
        {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer":"ngram_analyzer"

        }

      } 
    }
}
}
```

And search query:

```
{
  "from" : 0,
  "size" : 10,
 "query" : {
    "match" : {
        "title": 
        {
        "query":"press key han",
        "operator":"or",
        "analyzer":"standard"
      }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: I will try it today. Lets hope it will resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

What if you have your `match` something like this:

```
"query": {
        "match_phrase": {
          "text": {
            "query": "boca w"
          }
        }
      },
"sort":{
    "total":{
        "order":"desc"
       }
    },
"size":100
```

Or you could use the `wildcard` query:

```
"query": {
       "wildcard" : { 
            "yourfield" : "boca w*" 
        }
    }
```

This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16933800/elasticsearch-how-to-use-multi-match-with-wildcard) could be helpful. Hope it helps!