# Search for all data with multi_match

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

I am using `multi_match` search in Elasticsearch. How can I return all data using `multi_match`?

I would like to do something like this:
`curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/routines/_search?pretty=true&q=*:*'` but using the structure of `multi_match` that I have when I search for specific phrases.

My query looks like this:

```
{
            query: {
                bool: {
                    should: [
                        {
                            nested: {
                                path: "steps",
                                query: {
                                    nested: {
                                        path: "steps.products",
                                        query: {
                                            multi_match: {
                                                query: *,
                                                fields: [
                                                    "steps.products.name"
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            multi_match: {
                                query: *,
                                fields: [
                                    "title"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
```

I wish I could use `*` to match all the results but it doesn't work. How can I keep this query and change only the value set for `query`?

Comment: you might be interested in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16933800/elasticsearch-how-to-use-multi-match-with-wildcard

Answer (score 0):

**The multi-match query allows us to run a query on multiple fields. It is an extension of the match query.**

When you search for specific phrases with no field specified, using a multi-match query, then that defaults to extracting all the fields as mentioned in the [official documentataion](http://If%20no%20fields%20are%20provided,%20the%20multi_match%20query%20defaults%20to%20the%20index.query.default_field%20index%20settings,%20which%20in%20turn%20defaults%20to%20*.%20*%20extracts%20all%20fields%20in%20the%20mapping%20that%20are%20eligible%20to%20term%20queries%20and%20filters%20the%20metadata%20fields.%20All%20extracted%20fields%20are%20then%20combined%20to%20build%20a%20query.)

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":    "your-phrase"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've updated the question. Could you take a look? You current answer doesn't help me unfortunately.

Comment: @NorahJones I didn't get. May I know why you want to use `*` to match all the results, of a particular field?