# Elasticsearch find exact text in multiple fields using single query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document with multiple fields such as

"identifier" ( string ) analyzed

"description" ( string ) analyzed

"remark" ( string ) analyzed

of course the general scoring based queries work very well.

E.g. if I search for **blue car** it shows relevant results with the right scoring algorithm etc.

Although I have the requirement to implement a google like exact match query as well

E.g. **"blue car"** should only return documents where the exact phrase "blue car" appears **anywhere** in the text in **any of the fields**.

What is the best way to implement this ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, meaning a [`multi_match` with `phrase` type](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#_literal_fields_literal_and_per_field_boosting):

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "blue car",
      "fields": [
        "text",
        "message",
        "whatever"
      ],
      "type": "phrase"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried queries and I do not believe it is as simple as that. thanks a lot

Comment: I think this will not work for the exact match. Type "phrase" does a "match_phrase" which doesn't check the exact string. (Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26001002/elastic-search-difference-between-term-match-phrase-and-query-string). Instead, it checks if all the words of query are present in the same order.