# Exact match in Elasticsearch dis_max query

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I use php client of elastic search.

I elastic search I want to query multiple fields in the same time, but I want to search for exact match for **my_field_2**

```
'query' => [
    'dis_max' => [
    'queries' => [
        ['term' => ['my_field' => 'my_value']],
        ['term' => ['my_field_2' => 'my_value_2']]
    ]
]
]
```

I tried to add double quote around my_value_2:

```
['term' => ['my_field_2' => '"my_value_2"']]
```

How can I ensure to get only exact value for the second field?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exact match in elastic search query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37894448/exact-match-in-elastic-search-query)

Answer (score 0):

If you have not defined the mapping yourself, than Elasticsearch will create a `.keyword` field for every `text` field for `exact` search and `agss` use-cases. you can simply use the `my_field_2.keyword` in your search query in this case,

otherwise, you will have to define the `keyword` field in your mapping and than use it in your search query in order to do the exact search.