# How do i write a search query in elastic when the field name is unknown

Tags: elasticsearch

[image]

I want to use the elastic search to query documents who has the matching values of "dc883c6f24776ad6ce1f86c41b5cf87cfb784e85".

Please find the structure of the source document attached in the image. Is it possible to query this with something like below using *[wild char] when the field name is unknown for us.

```
 "query" : {
    "constant_score" : {
        "filter" : {
            "terms" : { 
                "commitId.persistence-statics-service.*":["dc883c6f24776ad6ce1f86c41b5cf87cfb784e85"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `query_string` or `multi_match` to specify a wildcard in the field name part. I think the `multi_match` is simpler though:

```
{
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "dc883c6f24776ad6ce1f86c41b5cf87cfb784e85",
          "fields": [
            "commitId.persistence-statics-service.*"
          ],
          "analyzer": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to Use query_string . Its very powerful in partial search in ES ,check my answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43321606/2357869) :-

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
       "fields" : ["commitId.persistence-statics-service.*"] ,
      "query": "*dc883c6f24776ad6ce1f86c41b5cf87cfb784e85*"
    }
  }
}
```

Query_string is more powerful than multi_match [link2](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html)