# ElasticSearch parsing special characters

Tags: database, elasticsearch

I've problem with parsing pipe "|" character in elasticsearch. When record have any special characters no result data. Below my query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "username": "john|doe@group.net"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [],
      "should": []
    }
  },
```

I tried use `"tokenizer":"uax_url_email"`, but not working

Comment: Can you provide an example document which should match the exact term( `john|doe@group.net` )?

Comment: I've database table which contain usernames like john|doe@group.net, and i need select this using elasticsearh via above query. thats all

Comment: if you are using ES 5.x and default mapping for field `username` then replace this line `"username": "john|doe@group.net"` with `"username.keyword": "john|doe@group.net"` and try it should work.

Comment: im using ES 2.4 ;/

Comment: What is the mapping of field `username`?if it is not_analyzed field then is it possible to make it `not_analyzed` field?

Comment: There is another way to have both `analyzed` and `not_analyzed` versions of a field using [multi fields concept](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/multi-fields.html)

Comment: It tourned out that, needed put "type":"phrase", now its okey. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with query_string ,Its working .I have tested in my system with default standard analyzer 
Try to Use query_string . Its very powerful in partial search in ES ,check my answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43321606/2357869) :-

:-

```
{ 

  "query": {
    "query_string": {
       "fields" : ["username"] ,
      "query": "john|doe@group.net"
    }
  }
}
```