# Like search in Elasticsearch

Tags: java, php, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-net

I am using elasticsearch for filtering and searching from json file and I am newbie in this technology. So I am little bit confused how to write like query in elasticsearch.

```
select * from table_name where 'field_name' like 'a%'
```

This is mysql query. How do I write this query in Elasticsearch? I am using elasticsearch version 0.90.7.

Comment: 0.90.7 is a very (very) old version of ES. I suggest using the latest release.

Comment: Also, please read the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-matching.html)! It covers many use cases and offers various solutions to what you need.

Comment: You can use [regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467067/how-to-search-for-a-part-of-a-word-with-elasticsearch/51843146#51843146).
It worked for me.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I would highly suggest updating your ElasticSearch version if possible, there have been significant changes since 0.9.x.

This question is not quite specific enough, as there are many ways ElasticSearch can fulfill this functionality, and they differ slightly on your overall goal. If you are looking to replicate that SQL query exactly then in this case use the wildcard query or prefix query.

Using a [wildcard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) query:

Note: Be careful with wildcard searches, they are slow. Avoid using wildcards at the beginning of your strings.

```
GET /my_index/table_name/_search
{
    "query": {
        "wildcard": {
            "field_name": "a*"
        }
    }
}
```

Or [Prefix query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/prefix-query.html)

```
GET /my_index/table_name/_search
{
    "query": {
        "prefix": {
            "field_name": "a"
        }
    }
}
```

Or [partial matching](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-matching.html):

Note: Do **NOT** blindly use partial matching, while there are corner cases for it's use, correct use of analyzers is almost always better.

Also this exact query will be equivalent to `LIKE '%a%'`, which again, could be better setup with correct use of mapping and a normal query search!

```
GET /my_index/table_name/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match_phrase": {
            "field_name": "a"
        }
    }
}
```

If you are reading this wondering about querying ES similarly for search-as-you-type I would suggest reading up on [edge-ngrams](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_ngrams_for_partial_matching.html), which relate to proper use of mapping depending on what you are attempting to do =)

Comment: as a kql in kibana you might try `message : "Unable to query openstack for*"  and message : "*retry"` to get `Unable to query openstack for*retry`

Answer (score 4):

```
GET /indexName/table_name/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match_phrase": {
            "field_name": "your partial text"
        }
    }
}
```

You can use `"type" : "phrase_prefix"` to prefix or post fix you search
Java code for the same:

```
AndFilterBuilder andFilterBuilder = FilterBuilders.andFilter();
 andFilterBuilder.add(FilterBuilders.queryFilter(QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("field_name",
          "your partial text")));
```

Gave 'and filter' example so that you can append extra filters if you want to.
Check this for more detail:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/slop.html

Answer (score 2):

Below query I wrote, this is something like

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE api='payment' AND api_v='v1' AND status='200' AND response LIKE '%expired%' AND response LIKE '%token%'
```

Please note table = document here

GET/POST both accepted

```
GET /transactions-d-2021.06.24/_search
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "match":{
                  "api":"payment"
               }
            },
            {
               "match":{
                  "api_v":"v1"
               }
            },
            {
               "match":{
                  "status":"200"
               }
            },
            {
               "wildcard":{
                  "response":"*expired*"
               }
            },
            {
               "wildcard":{
                  "response":"*token*"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: This ELK search query would take forever for an extensive dataset. Ironically, SQL is far faster than these NoSQL queries!

Answer (score 0):

Writing a custom bool query worked for me

```
@Query("{\"bool\":{\"should\":[{\"query_string\":{\"fields\":[\"field_name\"],\"query\":\"?0*\"}}]}}")
```