# Like query in AWS Elasticsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I want to use like query in Elasticsearch. Can anyone help me with some sample code that includes like query pattern

Have used wildcard in query but it is not working

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": {
                        wildcard : {
                            "title": "searchquery*",
                            "description": "searchquery*"
                        }
                    }
                    "fields": ["title", "description"]
                }
            },
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This may help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31176000/like-search-in-elasticsearch

Again,
As you want to use multi-match and 'like' functionality , then quick fix is to use query_string option as given at
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16933800/elasticsearch-how-to-use-multi-match-with-wildcard

Or try nGram option.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  As info, this really has nothing to do with AWS, but is just an Elasticsearch question.  I would suggest removing the AWS reference including the tag.

Comment: This can help [elasticsearch-how-to-use-multi-match-with-wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16933800/elasticsearch-how-to-use-multi-match-with-wildcard)

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
         {"match_phrase": {"title":  "searchquery*"}},
         {"match_phrase": {"description":  "searchquery*"}}
      ]
    }
 }
}
```