# Java Elastic Search: Search term like

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Similar to SQL I want to be able to search for terms, but instead of matching exact terms I want to be able to match terms that contains certain string say "abc".

Something like SQL's `LIKE "%abc%"`

At the moment I have the full term matcher like:

```
        AndFilterBuilder andFilter = FilterBuilders.andFilter();
        andFilter.add(FilterBuilders.rangeFilter("@timestamp").gt(start).lt(end));
        andFilter.add(FilterBuilders.termFilter("@host", "abc"));
```

Is there a way to do that? Regex may be?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467067/how-to-search-for-a-part-of-a-word-with-elasticsearch please do not use "\*abc\*", it will be very slow, use ngram as described in the above link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
andFilter.add(FilterBuilders.regexpFilter("@host", "*abc*"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer : ) I had just a small error in the regex it should be ".*abc.*". Otherwise it's working!