# how to perform partial match elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

i want to perform both exact match and partial match. for example, "Alize", so if i type "Ali" it should return the result of "Alize" as well. for this case i only can return the result if i type exact word "Alize".

```
POST /ecommerce/_search
'{
  "query": {
      "multi_match": {
        "fields": [
          "name"
        ],
        "operator": "AND",
        "query": "Ali*"
      }
    },
    "size": 20,
    "stored_fields": [
      "uid",
      "_source"
    ]
}`
```

Comment: Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467067/how-to-search-for-a-part-of-a-word-with-elasticsearch

Comment: so i have to use ngram?

Comment: You can. It would be much faster that way, specially if you have a large index.

Comment: is there is any other simple way to perform this?

Comment: Read: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/prefix-query.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use querystring query as following

```
"query": {
    "query_string": {
        "query": "Ali*",
        "fields": ["name"]
    }
}
```

Or use wildcard

```
"query": {
    "filtered": {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {"query": {"wildcard": {"name": {"value": "Ali*"}}}},
              ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Wildcard document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html)

Answer (score 0):

This solutions work perfectly for django_elasticsearch_dsl

```
search_keyword = search_keyword + "*"  
query = document_class.search().query(
        {
           "query_string": {
           "query": search_keyword,
           "fields": ["name", "code"]
           }
        }
```