# How to search for a part of a word with spring data elasticSearch

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

In my `Spring Data Elasticsearch` application I'd like to implement autocomplete functionality when user types a few chars and application will show him all possible variants with `query*`.

Right now I can't find a way how to properly implement it with Spring Data Elasticsearch.

For example I tried the following:

```
Criteria c = new Criteria("name").startsWith(query);
return elasticsearchTemplate.queryForPage(new CriteriaQuery(c, pageRequest), ESDecision.class);
```

It works for a single word query but in case of two or more words it returns error:

```
"Cannot constructQuery '*"security windows"'. Use expression or multiple clauses instead."
```

How to properly implement it in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have same requirement  , I have implemented same . **Querystring** will work for you .
If you have two token like  "security windows" than  you have to pass `"*security* *windows*"` than **Querystring** will return all possible data available . If you have one token like "security" than  you have to pass `"*security*"` .

One more explaination for this scenario ,check this answer -
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43278852/2357869

```
String aQueryString = "security windows" ;
String aQueryWithPartialSerach = null;
List<ESDecision> aESDecisions = null;


 // Enabling partial sarch
        if (aQueryString.contains(" ")) {
            List<String> aTokenList = Arrays.asList(aQueryString.split(" "));
            aQueryWithPartialSerach = String.join(" ", aTokenList.stream().map(p -> "*" + p + "*").collect(Collectors.toList()));
        } else {
            aQueryWithPartialSerach = "*" + aQueryString + "*";
        }
NativeSearchQueryBuilder aNativeSearchQueryBuilder = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder();
        aNativeSearchQueryBuilder.withIndices(indexName).withTypes(type).withPageable(new PageRequest(0, iPageRequestCount));
        final BoolQueryBuilder aQuery = new BoolQueryBuilder();

            aQuery.must(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(aQueryWithPartialSerach).defaultField("name"));

  NativeSearchQuery nativeSearchQuery = aNativeSearchQueryBuilder.withQuery(aQuery).build();
        aESDecisions = elasticsearchTemplate.queryForList(nativeSearchQuery, ESDecision.class);
        return aESDecisions;
```

Imports need to be done :-

```
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.NativeSearchQuery;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.NativeSearchQueryBuilder;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.SearchQuery;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.BoolQueryBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders;
```