# Query_string search is not working as expected

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose we have data like this:

```
{ "_id" : "1","name" : "Doeman John"}
{"_id" : "2","name" : "John"}
```

Query used:

```
{ 
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
       "fields" : ["name"] ,
      "query": "John"
    }
  }
}
```

Current result :

```
{ "_id" : "1","name" : "Doeman John"}
{"_id" : "2","name" : "John"}
```

Expected result:

```
{"_id" : "2","name" : "John"}
```

I am using Standard Analyzer. Could I achieve my `expected result` without changing any Analyzer setting?

Comment: No, you won't be able to achieve this without changing `analyzer` setting. You can use `multifield` in case you want to keep analyzed version as well.

Comment: Did not get your last point 'You can use multifield in case you want to keep analyzed version as well '  ?

Comment: That means you can create two fields for name. One will have "analyzed" settings and other will have "not analyzed". In your case you will search on not analyzed version.

Comment: See this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html

Answer (score 1):

You can not achieve this without changing `analyzer` settings.
In case you still want to use `Standard Analyzer`, you can make your field `multifield`.

```
 {
 "mappings": {
 "my_type": {
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "raw": { 
          "type":  "keyword"
          }
        }
      } 
     }
  }
 }
}
```

and then run your query on the `not_analyzed` version.

```
  {
   "query": {
   "term": {
   "name.raw": {
      "value": "John"
      }
    }
   }
  }
```

This will fetch results as per your requirement.

`