# Elasticsearch equal SQL %Like%

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, search, sql-like, elasticsearch-5

Coming from [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-matching.html) i'm asking myselve for the elasticsearch syntax for such querys:

```
WHERE text LIKE "%quick%"
  AND text LIKE "%brown%"
  AND text LIKE "%fox%"
```

my try (unfortunately without success)

```
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "text": [
                    "*quick*",
                    "*brown*",
                    "*fox*"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: You can use regexp.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467067/how-to-search-for-a-part-of-a-word-with-elasticsearch/51843146#51843146
It has worked for me.

Comment: You can use [regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467067/how-to-search-for-a-part-of-a-word-with-elasticsearch/51843146#51843146).
It has worked for me .
Good Luck.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using `bool` and `wildcard` to do such a query.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "wildcard": {
                        "text": "*quick*"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "wildcard": {
                        "text": "*brown*"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "wildcard": {
                        "text": "*fox*"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

> [**Wildcard Query**](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html#query-dsl-wildcard-query) Matches documents that have fields matching a wildcard expression (not analyzed). Supported wildcards are *, which matches any character sequence (including the empty one), and ?, which matches any single character.

Answer (score 1):

That's what you're looking for. Just put desired amount of wildcard queries in your bool/must:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "text": {
              "value": "*quick*"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "text": {
              "value": "*brown*"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "text": {
              "value": "*fox*"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```