# Elasticsearch Suggest+Synonyms+fuzziness

Tags: elasticsearch, fuzzy-search, search-suggestion, type-synonyms

I am looking for a way to implement the auto-suggest with synonyms & fuzziness

For example, when the user tried to search for "replce ar"
My synonym list has ar => audio record

So, the result should include the items matching 
changing audio record
replacing audio record
etc..,

Here we need  fuzziness because there is a typo on "replace" (in the user's search text)
Synonyms to match ar => audio record
Auto-suggest with regex pattern.

Is it possible to implement all the three features in a single field?

**Edit:**
a regex+fuzzy just throws error.
I haven't well explained my need of a regex-pattern.
so, i needed a Regex for doing a partial word lookup ('encyclopedic' contains 'cyclo').

now, after investigating [what options do i have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467067/how-to-search-for-a-part-of-a-word-with-elasticsearch) for this purpose, directing me to the [NGram Tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html#analysis-ngram-tokenizer) and looking into the other suggesters, i found that maybe [Phrase suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-phrase.html#_candidate_generators) is realy what I'm looking for, so I'll try it & tell you about.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use synonyms as well as fuzziness for suggestions.  The synonyms are handled by adding a synonym filter in your language analyzer and adding that filter to the analyzer.  Then, when you create the field mapping for the field(s) you want to use for suggestions, you assign that analyzer to that field.

As for fuzziness, that happens at query time.  Most text-based queries support a `fuzziness` option which allows you to specify how many corrections you want to allow.  The default `auto` value adjusts the number of corrections, depending on how long the term is, so that's usually best.

**Notional analysis setup** ([synonym_graph reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-graph-tokenfilter.html))

```
{
  "analysis": {
    "filter": {
      "synonyms": {
        "type": "synonym_graph",
        "expand": "false",
        "synonyms": [
          "ar => audio record"
        ]
      }
    },
    "analyzer": {
      "synonyms": {
        "tokenizer": "standard",
        "type": "custom",
        "filter": [
          "standard",
          "lowercase",
          "synonyms"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Notional Field Mapping** ([Analyzer + Mapping reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_testing_analyzers.html))

*(Note that the analyzer matches the name of the analyzer defined above)*

```
{
  "properties": {
    "suggestion": {
      "type": "text",
      "analyzer": "synonyms"
    }
  }
}
```

**Notional Query**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "suggestion": {
        "query": "replce ar",
        "fuzziness": "auto",
        "operator": "and"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that there are several different [options for suggestions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html), so depending on which option you use, you may need to adjust the way the field is mapped, or even add another token filter to the analyzer.  But analyzers are just made up of a series of token filters, so you can *usually* combine whatever token filters you need to achieve your goal.  Just make sure you understand what each filter is doing so you get the filters in the correct order.

If you get stuck in part of this process, just submit another question with the specific issue you're running into.  Good luck!

Comment: _just submit another question_: i don't understand why people recommending to branching out? 
for my opinion, the more a topic is concentrated - the better

Comment: I think it's because specific questions have a better chance of getting a specific answer.  For example, someone might not be interested in answering your initial question about integrating suggestions+synonyms+fuzziness, but they are willing to help with a specific question about setting up synonyms.  Also, the more questions there are on specific topics, the better it is for users who are searching for help with that topic.