# Subwordsearch in elasticsearch using ngram does not work

Tags: elasticsearch, n-gram

I would like to perform a **simple_query_string** search in Elasticsearch while having a sub-word matching.
For example if a would have a filename: "C:\Users\Sven Onderbeke\Documents\Arduino"
Than I would want this filename listed if my searchterm is for example "ocumen".

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467067/how-to-search-for-a-part-of-a-word-with-elasticsearch) suggested to use ngram to match with parts of the word. I tried to implement it as follows (in Python) but I get zero results while I expect one:

```
test_mapping = {
    "properties": {
        "filename": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "my_index_analyzer"
        },
    }
}


def create_index(index_name, mapping):
    created = False
    # index settings
    settings = {
        "settings": {
            "number_of_shards": 1,
            "number_of_replicas": 0,
        },


    "analysis": {
      "index_analyzer": {
        "my_index_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "mynGram"
          ]
        }
      },
      "search_analyzer": {
        "my_search_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "standard",
            "lowercase",
            "mynGram"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "mynGram": {
          "type": "nGram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 50
        }
      }
    },

        "mappings": mapping
    }
    try:
        if not es.indices.exists(index_name):
            # Ignore 400 means to ignore "Index Already Exist" error.
            es.indices.create(index=index_name, ignore=400, body=settings)
            print(f'Created Index: {index_name}')
            created = True
    except Exception as ex:
        print(str(ex))
    finally:
        return created

create_index("test", test_mapping)

doc = {
    'filename': r"C:\Users\Sven Onderbeke\Documents\Arduino",

}
es.index(index="test", document=doc)

needle = "ocumen"

q = {
    "simple_query_string": {
        "query": needle,
        "default_operator": "and"
    }
}

res = es.search(index="test", query=q)
print(res)
for hit in res['hits']['hits']:
    print(hit)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your solution isn't working is because you haven't provided analyzer on the property named as `field` while defining mapping. Update mapping as below and then reindex all documents.

```
test_mapping = {
    "properties": {
        "filename": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "my_index_analyzer"
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed my code and question accordingly, but still no results. A needle of "*" does return the line (as a test). needle = "*ocumen *" does get 0 results which is also strange